# How can I select server name in below script using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
$s = Get-Content @("C:\servers.txt") | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Acl $_ ).Access |
        Select-Object IdentityReference, FileSystemRights, AccessControlType,
                      IsInherited 
} | Export-Csv "C:\t8.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: It would be helpful is you showed us (part of) the actual content of `C:\servers.txt`

Comment: Do you want the contents of `C:\servers.txt` to be displayed in your `t8.csv` as a different column named **Server**?

Answer (score 0):

You mean how you can add the servername as an additional column to the output CSV? Simply add it with a calculated property in the `Select-Object`:

```
$server = $_
(Get-Acl $server).Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Servername';e={$server}}, IdentityReference, ...
```

Note that your assignment `$s = ...` is pointless, because all output goes to the CSV, so nothing is ever assigned to `$s`.